# In Django, how can I acccess request.meta and the http_referer in a class-based view like UpdateView?

Tags: django

Well, actually the question is in the title :)

I want to have an UpdateView with different redirects depending on the referer from which the update is called.

**Update:** Initially, my question was misleading. I did not only want to access the meta data, but especially the http_referer of the site which led to the updateview.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on a view. If you use generic CBV you should call `self.request.meta` more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering). But if you just extend the `View` class you can do it like in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views) namely

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        request.meta
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Comment: I wanted to the generic CBV.
class RgUpdate(UpdateView):
model = ...
template_name = ...
fields = ...
def get_success_url(self):
[here I wanted to say something like if self.request.meta['http_referer'] == ...: return reverse ...

Comment: Thanks, but when I access self.request.meta['HTTP_REFERER'] I only get the URL of the update view and not the URL of the page from which I directed to the updateview.

Comment: Well your question "In Django, how can I acccess request.meta in a class-based view like UpdateView?" was correctly answered also "Well, actually the question is in the title :)" confirms that it was your question. The refferer part is another question. Let others see that there is an answer for the question you asked if they have similar one.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using

```
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ref'] = self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
        return context
    def get_success_url(self):
        if 'uebersichteingaben_nichtabgeschlossen' in self.request.POST['ref']:
            return reverse_lazy(url_app_name + 'uebersichteingaben_nichtabgeschlossen')
        else:
            return reverse_lazy(url_app_name + 'uebersichteingaben_alle')
```

in the CBV. And I used the context['ref'] as hidden input in the template.